# How to run a bash script in a loop

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics

i wrote a bash script in order to pull substrings and save it to an output file from two input files that looks like this:
input file 1

```
>genotype1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

input file 2

```
gene1 10 20
gene2 40 50
genen x y
```

my script

```
>output_file

cat input_file2 | while read row; do
    echo $row > temp
    geneName=`awk '{print $1}' temp`
    startPos=`awk '{print $2}' temp`
    endPos=`awk '{print $3}' temp`
    length=$(expr $endPos - $startPos)
    for i in temp; do
        echo ">${geneName}" >> genes_fasta
        awk -v S=$startPos -v L=$length '{print substr($0,S,L)}' input_file1 >> output file

    done
done
```

how can i make it work in a loop for more than one string in the input file 1?
new input file looks like this:

```
>genotype1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>genotype2
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
>genotypen...
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn...
```

I would like to have a different out file for every genotype and that the file name would be the genotype name.
thank you!

Comment: `for i in temp` doesn't read the file. It just sets the variable `i` to the string `temp`.

Comment: Why are you using all those `awk` commands just to split the line? Why not `while read geneName startPos endPos`

Comment: Could you please confirm that your Input_file1's 1st column without `>` should be compared to 1st column of Input_file2's 1st column?

Comment: You will want to refactor this into a single Awk script anyway. This is a horrible, horrible shell script but the equivalent Awk script will be quite elegant. Read up on Awk's associative arrays and the `NR==FNR` idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, would you try the following:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {
    name[NR] = $1
    start[NR] = $2
    len[NR] = $3 - $2
    count = NR
    next
}
/^>/ {
    sub(/^>/,"")
    genotype=$0
    next
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        print ">" name[i] > genotype
        print substr($0, start[i], len[i]) >> genotype
    }
    close(genotype)
}' input_file2 input_file1
```

input_file1:

```
>genotype1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>genotype2
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
>genotype3
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
```

Input_file2:

```
gene1 10 20
gene2 40 50
gene3 20 25
```

**[Results]**
genotype1:

```
>gene1
aaaaaaaaaa
>gene2
aaaaaaaaaa
>gene3
aaaaa
```

genotype2:

```
>gene1
bbbbbbbbbb
>gene2
bbbbbbbbbb
>gene3
bbbbb
```

genotype3:

```
>gene1
nnnnnnnnnn
>gene2
nnnnnnnnnn
>gene3
nnnnn
```

**[EDIT]**
If you want to store the output files to a different directory,
please try the following instead:

```
dir="./outdir"  # directory name to store the output files
                # you can modify the name as you want
mkdir -p "$dir"

awk -v dir="$dir" '
FNR==NR {
    name[NR] = $1
    start[NR] = $2
    len[NR] = $3 - $2
    count = NR
    next
}
/^>/ {
    sub(/^>/,"")
    genotype=$0
    next
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        print ">" name[i] > dir"/"genotype
        print substr($0, start[i], len[i]) >> dir"/"genotype
    }
    close(dir"/"genotype)
}' input_file2 input_file1
```

- The 1st two lines are executed in bash to define and mkdir the destination directory.
- Then the directory name is passed to `awk` via `-v` option

Hope this helps.

Comment: HELPS A TON! thank you! any chance i can save all the output files in a different directory ?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer by adding the requested version at the bottom. BR.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, where I am assuming that your Input_file1's column which starts with `>` should be compared with 1st column of Input_file2's first column (since samples are confusing so based on OP's attempt this has been written).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  start_point[$1]=$2
  end_point[$1]=$3
  next
}
/^>/{
  sub(/^>/,"")
  val=$0
  next
}
{
  print val ORS substr($0,start_point[val],end_point[val])
  val=""
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named Input_file2 is being read.
  start_point[$1]=$2                                            ##Creating an array named start_point with index $1 of current line and its value is $2.
  end_point[$1]=$3                                              ##Creating an array named end_point with index $1 of current line and its value is $3.
  next                                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/{                                                           ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  sub(/^>/,"")                                                  ##Substituting starting > with NULL.
  val=$0                                                        ##Creating a variable val whose value is $0.
  next                                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print val ORS substr($0,start_point[val],end_point[val])      ##Printing val  newline(ORS) and sub-string of current line whose start value is value of start_point[val] and end point is value of end_point[val].
  val=""                                                        ##Nullifying variable val here.
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1                                     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: tried to run it and it didn't work. should i run it in addition to my script or it will generate the same output?

Comment: the script give just the genotype name

Comment: @ZivAttia, are your samples are the correct ones? Could you please do lemme know how are you comparing columns in these 2 different files please?

Comment: I suppose the input_file1's 1st column starting with `>` contains `genotype`
while the input_file2's 1st colums holds `gene name`. They will need to be
treated separatety. Then how about indexing the arrays `start_point` et al.
with the order of appearance (maybe `NR`), not with the gene name?

Comment: @tshiono, yeah right, even I was thinking the same but waiting for OP to confirm, asked this 2 times let's see :)

Comment: yes samples are correct if I have only one genotype it works fine i want to run it on a bigger data file. is there a way to run the script i wrote on the 2nd and 3rd line on file 1 and go to the next 2 lines ?